# LINQ adding or summing items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I've been trying to find an answer to my question but the wording is difficult.

Let say i have the following:

- a first table of parties: `party 1, party 2, party 3, party 4`
- a second table that records who belongs to what party:

  ```
  party 1 - alex, party 1 - cynthia
  party 2 - charles
  party 3 - ana, party 3 - david
  ```

How could I build a linq query that would tell me how many people are going to each party, so the result would be:

```
party 1 , 2 people
party 2 , 1 people
party 3 , 2 people
```

Comment: So it's really more **counting** the party goers for each party

Answer (score 5):

```
list.GroupBy(x => x.Party)
    .Select(x => new { Party = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });
```